# Uploading to subversion repo via FTP or syncing with web server

Tags: svn, web, ftp, tortoisesvn

I have a bunch of WordPress sites that I am managing. I am tasked with regularly backing them up to the companies subversion server.

I have found a centralized tool where I can administer, update, manage and backup all of the sites. This tool enables backups to be sent via FTP automatically.

Is it possible to upload to a subversion server via FTP?

If not, is it possible for a file in subversion to automatically sync to a file on a webserver which would be the middle man for these FTP backups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am tasked with regularly backing them up to the companies subversion server.

Subversion is not a backup system. If you need backups, get a backup solution.

If you have code changes that are on your production systems that you need versioned, then your whole process is backwards - develop lcoally, commit to Subversion, promote to test, run tests, promote to production.

IOW, all of the code on your Wordpress site(s) should be in Subversion long before it ever got to the production Wordpress server.

> Is it possible to upload to a subversion server via FTP?

No, Subversion does not have an FTP component. You can serve a repository with HTTP(s), the custom Subversion server svnserve, or access svnserve through an SSH tunnel.

> it possible for a file in subversion to automatically sync to a file on a webserver which would be the middle man for these FTP backups?

This just sounds like adding more moving parts to little benefit (and more risk).

- Backup your web server using proper backup software.
- Fix your development & promotion process such that nothing lands on the production server until it's already passed through Subversion.
- Do not layer more bad ideas on top of a poorly controlled environment/process.

Comment: I'm an intern and I have pretty much zero say about process. I'm following instructions. Being critical of a process I can't control isn't going to help me solve my task.